# PHP filesize reporting old size

Tags: php, filesize

The following code is part of a PHP web-service I've written.  It takes some uploaded Base64 data, decodes it, and appends it to a file.  This all works fine.

The problem is that when I read the file size after the append operation I get the size the file was before the append operation.

```
$fileOut = fopen($filepath.$filename, "ab")
fwrite($fileOut, base64_decode($data));
fflush($fileOut);
fclose($fileOut);

$newSize = filesize($filepath.$filename);   // gives old file size
```

What am I doing wrong?

System is:

- PHP 5.2.14
- Apache 2.2.16
- Linux kernel 2.6.18

Comment: `b` is used for outputting binary data. It shouldn't cause the issue.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

On Linux based systems, data fetched by `filesize()` is "statcached".

Try calling [`clearstatcache();`](http://www.php.net/clearstatcache) before the filesize call.

Answer (score 12):

According to the PHP manual:

> The results of this function are
> cached. See clearstatcache() for more
> details.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Basically, you have to clear the stat cache after the file operation:

```
$fileOut = fopen($filepath.$filename, "ab")
fwrite($fileOut, base64_decode($data));
fflush($fileOut);
fclose($fileOut);

clearstatcache();

$newSize = filesize($filepath.$filename);
```

Answer (score 4):

PHP stores all file metadata it reads in a cache, so it's likely that the file size is already stored in that cache, and you need to clear it. See [clearstatcache](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) and call it before you call `filesize`.