# filesize not update after change file

Tags: php, filesize

PHP code

```
echo filesize("a.jpg")."<br/>";

imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg("a.jpg"), "a.jpg", 50);

echo filesize("a.jpg");
```

Output

```
73104
73104
```

I have change quality of image but `filesize` not changed!!!

However, the file size changed?!
[image]

why function `filesize` not updated immediate after change file?

My image(size 72k)
 [image]

Comment: Please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3748002/3647441

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [the manual](http://php.net/filesize) puts it:

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See [`clearstatcache()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) for more details.