# PHP fwrite mode "r+" beyond EOF not working, XAMPP, Windows 10 x64

Tags: php, xampp, windows-10, 64-bit

I'm trying to read and write data from a file using fread/fwrite with file open mode "r+" under flock. When I use fwrite to write a string longer than the original length of the file when it was opened, it gets truncated. Running the latest version of XAMPP on Windows 10 x64, PHP 7.3.7.0.

I have checked the return values of all method calls surrounding fwrite and the output seems cryptic to me unless there's something obvious I'm missing. I also tried truncating the file to its new extended size prior to the fwrite operation.

PrvOpen opens the file using file mode "r+" the obtains an exclusive lock to it using flock(). PrvClose releases the lock then closes the file.

```
public function SetStatus($name, $status)
{
    $fp = $this->PrvOpen();

    $fdata = fread($fp, filesize($this->path));
    echo("SetStatus: fdata in: $fdata<br/>");

    $allTasks = unserialize($fdata);
    $allTasks[$name] = $status;

    $this->PrvClear($fp);
    $fdata = serialize($allTasks);
    echo("SetStatus: fdata out: $fdata<br/>");

    $dataLength = mb_strlen($fdata);
    echo("SetStatus: data length: $dataLength<br/>");

    $truncResult = ftruncate($fp, mb_strlen($fdata));
    echo("SetStatus: truncate result: $truncResult<br/>");

    $seekResult = fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    echo("SetStatus: seek result: $seekResult<br/>");

    $cnt = fwrite($fp, $fdata);
    echo("SetStatus: count written: $cnt/" . mb_strlen($fdata) . "<br/>");

    $flushResult = fflush($fp);
    echo("SetStatus: flush result: $flushResult<br/>");

    $fpos = ftell($fp);
    echo("SetStatus: file position: $fpos<br/>");

    echo("SetStatus: filesize before close: " . filesize($this->path) . "<br/>");

    $this->PrvClose($fp);
    echo("SetStatus: filesize after close: " . filesize($this->path) . "<br/>");
}
```

Browser output is displayed below. You can see the return values of all operations surrounding fwrite. It successfully writes 35 bytes out to the file. The file position marker is at 35 bytes. Flush is successful. All operations are successful, yet the file size after it's written is only 6 bytes, which was its original size when opened.

In a subsequent operation whose debug output is also shown, the file is opened and its contents are displayed which are truncated to the first 6 characters.

```
SetStatus: fdata in: a:0:{}
SetStatus: fdata out: a:1:{s:8:"testtask";s:7:"running";}
SetStatus: data length: 35
SetStatus: truncate result: 1
SetStatus: seek result: 0
SetStatus: count written: 35/35
SetStatus: flush result: 1
SetStatus: file position: 35
SetStatus: filesize before close: 6
SetStatus: filesize after close: 6

Delete: file size: 6
Delete: fdata in: a:1:{s
```

The background is that I'm trying to write a class or set of classes to coordinate the running of asynchronous background processes alongside the communication of status information. I created an interface to do this and created a file implementation of it which serializes/deserializes task status information to/from a file.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747982/php-filesize-reporting-old-size, if it helps this can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks. That did fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question. As Nigel Ren pointed out, it was a result of failing to clear PHP's stat cache.